# PHP IF statement check for radio button inside jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, html

I am using the code below to have an add button in html to add a new textbox and radio buttons to the page when I click the add button. The names of the textboxes added are an input name plus an added number (the number of clicks) to differentiate the input data into different variables when I want to use it for different queries. I use this input(input is numeric) with the radio buttons to determine if I should query a certain data above or below the specified number, based on which radio button is checked.

```
<input id="btnAdd" type="button" value="Add" />
<br />
<div id="TextBoxContainer">
</div>
<br />

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        var click_number = 0;
        $("#btnAdd").bind("click", function () {
            var input = $("<label>input &nbsp;<textarea rows='1' name='input_"+ click_number +"'><?php echo $_POST['input_"+ click_number +"']; ?></textarea></label>&nbsp;");
            var above_below = $("<input type='radio' name='abovebelow_"+ click_number +"' id='above_"+ click_number +"' value='Above' <?php if(isset($_POST['abovebelow_"+ click_number +"']) && $_POST['abovebelow_"+ click_number +"'] == 'Above') echo \"checked='checked'\"; ?>><label for='above_"+ click_number +"'>Above</label><input type='radio' name='abovebelow_"+ click_number +"' id='below_"+ click_number +"' value='Below' <?php if(isset($_POST['abovebelow_"+ click_number +"']) && $_POST['abovebelow_"+ click_number +"'] == 'Below') echo \"checked='checked'\"; ?>><label for='below_"+ click_number +"'>Below</label><br/>&nbsp;");
            hgcBio.appendTo('#TextBoxContainer');
            above_below.appendTo('#TextBoxContainer');
            click_number++;
});
</script>
```

Currently, the html works when not using it in jQuery, but when in this jQuery format the radio buttons don't work. I have narrowed the error down to the php code that is in the above/below variable:

```
<?php if(isset($_POST['abovebelow_"+ click_number +"']) && $_POST['abovebelow_"+ click_number +"'] == 'Above') echo \"checked='checked'\"; ?>
```

because when I delete this part, I no longer get an error message. The error message is "Parse error: parse error, expecting `"identifier (T_STRING)"'" on that line. Since I have used php in other parts of the jQuery (the input variable), I'm guessing the problem is the if statement? Is there another way to use an if statement here? Or possible another way to do this?

Comment: Some of the strings in the if statement seem to be incorrectly formatted. Is click_number supposed to be a php variable? Why is the first char after echo a backslash?

Comment: no its a jQuery variable. the backslash is to escape the quotation marks. I could have also just used single quotes there but it was more for a visibility reason on my part.

Comment: If you would like to populate Javascript with data from PHP, Look into jquery's `$.ajax()` method, as well as `json_encode()` on the PHP side. I don't particularly recommend this way as it can cause _a lot_ of problems later on down the road.

Comment: you can't concatenate strings and variables with `+` sign in PHP. Use dot `.` instead of plus sign

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it just simple like

```
<?php 
    if(isset($_POST['abovebelow_". click_number ."']) 
         && $_POST['abovebelow_". click_number ."'] == 'Above') 
        echo "\"checked='checked'\""; 
?>
```

(i.e. you forgot double qoutes before and after the printed string. Also the concatenation of string should be using `.` not `+` in php, as mentioned in comments)

Comment: I believe this will fix the error, but notice that inside the POST brackets things are a bit strange. The dot doesn't concatenate anything sine it's all inside single quotes, and even if it weren't, variables in php start with $. I think there is some mix up here, but, as I said, the error mentioned in the question should be fixed with your change.

Comment: yeah I forgot the . to concatenate the string but the double quotes are not correct. that wouldn't match the whole statement in quotes (the escaped double quotes are already there to cover the echo'd string). --> confirmed by trying it and it unquoted large parts of the whole statement.

Comment: edit: I see I misinterpreted what you said and yeah I forgot that the escaped quotes must be inside the unescaped quotes. I was thinking you meant adding another set of quotes hence why it didn't work. thanks!